# Как использовать изменения из несмерженной ветки?

Tags: git, контроль-версий, git-merge, git-rebase

Добавил в ветке `A` обновление компилятора для проекта. Ветка `A` пока не замержена в `master`. Хочу добавить фичу в ветке `C`, причём код фичи использует возможности нового компилятора. Как правильно с точки зрения VCS надо поступить? Чекаут от мастера + мерж ветки `A`? Ребэйз? Чекаут от `A` + мерж мастера? Ещё как-то?

Замержить `A` в мастер и потом начать делать `C` я не могу.

Comment: замержить А в мастер. Потом сделать ребейз С на мастере. Почему так? да все просто. Если сделать ребейз С на А, и потом замержить С, то А туда попадет. А это явно не то, что нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim я не могу в мастер мержить, `A` должен ревью пройти, прежде чем лид его замержит. А в это время надо разрабатывать `C`

Comment: Форкнутся от А. Когда А смержится в мастер поребейзится на мастер

Comment: @AlexeyTen почему так?

Comment: А почему нет? Гиту всё равно, а мне, например, так проще

Comment: можно так, как и @AlexeyTen пишет. Но тут есть одна маленькая штука - нужно явно в тикет написать, что одно зависит от другого. Потому, что может выявится, что изменения от С - это критический фикс, а изменения А - это так, пока никому не интересно.